# jQuery.validate ignore password

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I use jquery.validate.js to validate the forms on our site. Today I updated the version of the validation plugin to v 1.9 and since then I have a problem with password validations on site.

I found why that is happen and now I looking for "correct" way to solve it.
In previous version the method attributeRules was as follows:

```
attributeRules: function (element) {
            var rules = {};
            var $element = $(element);

            for (var method in $.validator.methods) {
                var value = $element.attr(method);                      
                if (value) {
                    rules[method] = value;
                }
            }    

            // maxlength may be returned as -1, 2147483647 (IE) and 524288 (safari) for text inputs
            if (rules.maxlength && /-1|2147483647|524288/.test(rules.maxlength)) {
                delete rules.maxlength;
            }

            return rules;
        }
```

In version 1.9, it looks a little bit differ:

```
attributeRules: function (element) {
            var rules = {};
            var $element = $(element);

            for (var method in $.validator.methods) {
                var value;

                // If .prop exists (jQuery >= 1.6), use it to get true/false for required
                if (method === 'required' && typeof $.fn.prop === 'function') {
                    value = $element.prop(method);
                } else {
                    value = $element.attr(method);
                }

                if (value) {
                    rules[method] = value;
                } else if ($element[0].getAttribute("type") === method) {
                    rules[method] = true;
                }
            }


            // maxlength may be returned as -1, 2147483647 (IE) and 524288 (safari) for text inputs
            if (rules.maxlength && /-1|2147483647|524288/.test(rules.maxlength)) {
                delete rules.maxlength;
            }

            return rules;
        }
```

I understand from that, that in previous versions, the method didn't check the type attribute of input element and didn't add "password" validator. In ver 1.9 it checks if element has type "password" and adds validator.

The question:
How to tell to jQuery.validator to ignore inputs with "password" type?

Thanks

Comment: Describe your problem. What do you really need?

Comment: I want to leave the validation rule "password" but I don't want that plugin will automatically validate all inputs with type='password'

Comment: What plugin do you use? https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: I use jquery.validate.js from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: I didn't understand you. How do you want to validate `input[type="password"]` (cause you want to leave `password` rule), but not to validate those inputs? Why do you need rule `password`, when you don't want to validate them?

Comment: I have several fields for password on page. Some of them I need to validate and some of them no. Plugin has a password validation rule, but since ver 1.9, plugin validates automatically all password fields on page. In previous versions, on fields that i need to validate, i was added a specific CSS class.

Comment: Can you provide some jsfiddle? You can post the plugin code to the `<script>` tag in the head.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ignore option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  You can provide any selector to it, so what might work for you is something like this:

```
$('form').validate({
    ignore:'input[type="password"]'
});
```

If that is too general, I suggest adding a class such as `ignoreValidation` to all the appropriate inputs, and then use `'.ignoreValidation'` in the `ignore` option.